# Email error while sending mail from C# code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

How to resolve this? My code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
mail.To.Add(email);
mail.Subject = "Forgot Password";
mail.Body = SendMessage;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential(EmailUsername, EmailPassword);
SmtpServer.Credentials = myCreds;
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Webconfig as follows

```
<add key="FromAddress" value="xxxxxxx@gmail.com"/>
<add key="EmailUsername" value="xxxxxxx@gmail.com"/>
<add key="EmailPassword" value="Josco@321"/>
```

Changed my email settings as follows.

[image]

FromAddress and EmailUsername are same email.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but MailMessage and SmtpClient both implement IDisposable, and in case of SmtpClient in particular, you can actually exhaust resources if you don't dispose.

Comment: Be sure to change your password as it is showing in the question ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you set `SmtpClient.Credentials` **AFTER** calling `SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false`.

The order is important as setting `SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false` will reset `SmtpClient.Credentials` to null.